# Let $S = \{1, 2, 3\}$. Select all those that give equivalence relations on $S$.

Tags: equivalence-relations

Q: Let $S = \{1, 2, 3\}$. Each of the following subsets of $S \times S$ gives a relation on $S$.

Select all those that give equivalence relations on $S$.

a) $\{(1, 1),(1, 2),(2, 1),(2, 2),(3, 2),(3, 3)\}$

(b) $\{(1, 1)\}$

(c) $\{(1, 1),(1, 2),(1, 3),(2, 1),(2, 2),(2, 3),(3, 1),(3, 2)\}$

(d) $\{(1, 1),(1, 3),(2, 2),(2, 3),(3, 1),(3, 2),(3, 3)\}$

I'm stuck on this question. I said it was b) but I'm not sure if I'm right.

I would really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Thanks, but i didnt ask for a MathJax tutorial. I think what i wrote is clearly legible.

Comment: Did you know, what is equivalence relation?

Comment: -1 for an arrogant comment to being pointed to a MathJax tutorial.

Comment: @Henrik aren't you suppose to -1 if the question is bad or doesn't make sense or whatever, not because i was being 'mean' as that has nothing to do with maths.

Comment: @Jane no, being mean is legitimate reason for downvote. This is a forum, so we want nice atmosphere before all. We help each other because we want to help

Comment: @Jane: I wasn't calling you mean, I was calling your comment arrogant, there's a difference (and I'm not a native english speaker) and I stand by that statement, you could have chosen just to ignore the link, but you had to say that you found it unneeded.

Comment: I apologise in that case. Im sorry @Shaun and to the rest for being so arrogant.

Comment: This should be deleted for complete lack of personal input (just like many other questions by this OP).

Answer (score 2):

**Answer: none**(may be you had done typo while typing options)

a relation which is identity, symmetric and transitive is called the equivalence relation!

Clearly, $(b)$ is **not** equivalence relation! Since it is not identity relation(clearly you can see $(2,2), (3,3)∉\{(1,1)\}$)

Similarly, $(c)$ is not equivalence relation(as $(3,3)∉$**Set**)

further, (d) is not transitive! (Since $(2,1)∉$**Set**) hence not equivalence!

Infact, (a) is also not equivalence!  Since it is not symmetric (as $(2,3)∉$**set**)